# I'm trying to make a 8bit 4-1 selector circuit using vhdl. can someone help me what's wrong with this code?

Tags: vhdl

this is the vhdl code. this one has no error

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sel4_1 is
   port( A, B, C, D : in std_logic;
     SEL        : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
     outsgnl    : out std_logic );
   end sel4_1;

architecture EX1 of sel4_1 is
begin

process(A, B, C, D, SEL)
begin
case SEL is
   when "00" => outsgnl <= A;
   when "01" => outsgnl <= B;
   when "10" => outsgnl <= C;
   when others => outsgnl <= D;
end case;
end process;

end EX1;
```

---

this is the testbench which has the error

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity TESTBENCH is
end TESTBENCH;

architecture RTL of TESTBENCH is

component sel4_1

   port(A,B,C,D : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        outsgnl : out std_logic);

end component;

signal INA, INB, INC, IND, OUTSGNL : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal SEL : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin
   U0: sel4_1 port map(INA, INB, INC, IND, SEL, OUTSGNL);
   process
   begin
     INA <= "11111111";
     INB <= "11110000";
     INC <= "00001111";
     IND <= "00000000";

     SEL <= "00"; wait for 10 ns;
     SEL <= "01"; wait for 10 ns;
     SEL <= "10"; wait for 10 ns;
     SEL <= "11"; wait for 10 ns;

     wait;
   end process;
end RTL;
```

the error that came out is 
testbench.vhdl:19:27: can't associate 'ina' with signal interface "ina"

testbench.vhdl:19:27: (type of 'ina' is std_logic)

testbench.vhdl:11:9: (type of signal interface "ina" is a subtype of std_logic_vector)

Comment: When analyzing (compiling) testbench, the component declaration is missing SEL and has outsgnl declared as std_logic (not std_logic_vector (7 downto 0). sel4_1 doesn't match that component declaration either. Either correct the component declaration to match the entity sel4_1 and use a generate statement to instantiate it 8 times or edit the entity sel4_1 to make it's A,B,C,D and outsignl ports std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) (and make the first suggested changes to the component declaration). The latter simulates successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your entity `sel4_1`and your component `sel_4_1` are not the same. Your A,B,C,D ports are `std_logic` in the first one but `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)` in the second one.

Change the entity (or component) with what you really need and it should work properly.

Comment: In addition to not declaring ports A,B,C, and D of sel4_1 as std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) (they are std_logic), the component declaration for sel4_1 is missing a declaration for SEL and outsgnl should be declared as a std_logic_vector (7 downto 0). THEN the testbench simulates correctly - [testbench.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rywhv.png).

Comment: thank you so much both of you! finally i'm able to compile and simulates it

Answer (score 0):

this is the code after making some corrections:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sel4_1 is
   port( A, B, C, D : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        SEL         : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        outsgnl     : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) );
   end sel4_1;

architecture EX1 of sel4_1 is
begin

process(A, B, C, D, SEL)
begin
case SEL is
   when "00" => outsgnl <= A;
   when "01" => outsgnl <= B;
   when "10" => outsgnl <= C;
   when others => outsgnl <= D;
end case;
end process;

end EX1;
```

---

testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity TESTBENCH is
end TESTBENCH;

architecture RTL of TESTBENCH is

component sel4_1
   port(A,B,C,D : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        SEL     : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        OUTSGNL : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end component;

signal INA, INB, INC, IND, OUTSGNL : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal SEL : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin
   U0: sel4_1 port map(INA, INB, INC, IND, SEL, OUTSGNL);
   process
   begin
     INA <= "11111111";
     INB <= "11110000";
     INC <= "00001111";
     IND <= "00000000";

     SEL <= "00"; wait for 10 ns;
     SEL <= "01"; wait for 10 ns;
     SEL <= "10"; wait for 10 ns;
     SEL <= "11"; wait for 10 ns;

     wait;
   end process;
end RTL;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Hakim's (perfectly correct) suggestion, there is a concurrent way to do the same thing.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sel4_1 is
   port( A, B, C, D : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        SEL         : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        outsgnl     : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) );
   end sel4_1;

architecture EX1 of sel4_1 is
begin

  with SEL select
    outsgnl <= A when "00",
               B when "01",
               C when "10",
               D when others;
end EX1;
```

I prefer to avoid processes for anything other than clocked processes.  A missing signal in the sensitivity list will lead to simulation/synthesis mismatches.  And maintaining those sensitivity lists can become a bear.  And if there is a need for a combination process, the list should be very small.  (And, yes, there is VHDL-2008's `all`, which helps.)

Comment: thanks! I'm still a beginner in VHDL. so anything that is suggested will be a lot of help to me